# How to retrieve records efficiently using indices in dynamodb aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I want to fetch records of all male or female students from *class 5 to class 11* who have secured between **x1** and **x2** marks in maths, between **y1** and **y2** marks in science, between **z1** and **z2** marks in english and between **w1** and **w2** marks in social...

My model looks as follows:

```
type StudentMarks
    @model
    @key(
        name: "filterbyClassAndMarks"
        fields: [
            "gender"
            "classCode"
            "mathsMarks"
            "socialMarks"
            "englishMarks"
            "scienceMarks"
        ]
        queryField: "filterbyClassAndMarks"
    )
    @auth(
        rules: [
            { allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [read] }
            { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] }
        ]
    ) {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    gender: String
    classCode: String
    mathsMarks: String
    socialMarks: String
    englishMarks: String
    scienceMarks: String
}
```

The GSI created with gender as the partition key(hashkey) and compound sort/range key with classCode, mathMarks, socialMarks, scienceMarks, englishMarks fields [is showing item count as 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lwUd.png)

I am trying to query using the following graphql:

```
    const listOfStudents = await API.graphql({
                query: queries.filterbyClassAndMarks,
                variables: {
                    gender: "m",
                    classCodeMathsMarksSocialMarksEnglishMarksScienceMarks: {
                        between: [
                            {
                                classCode: "05",
                                mathsMarks: "06",
                                scienceMarks: "07",
                                englishMarks: "04",
                                socialMarks: "05",
                            },
                            {
                                classCode: "11",
                                mathsMarks: "90",
                                scienceMarks: "91",
                                englishMarks: "95",
                                socialMarks: "92",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                authMode: "AWS_IAM",
            });
```

[This table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9UJe.png) with 11 records should return 4 records as shown in green

The cloud watch logs are as below:

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "filterbyClassAndMarks"
    ],
    "fieldName": "filterbyClassAndMarks",
    "resolverArn": "arn:aws:appsync:ap-south-1:488377001042:apis/4tbr6xolzjfctl5tdbiur7jqnu/types/Query/resolvers/filterbyClassAndMarks",
    "requestId": "5de45e66-1a5d-44dd-80cc-1a5b93a3c3aa",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "gender": "m",
            "classCodeMathsMarksSocialMarksEnglishMarksScienceMarks": {
                "between": [
                    {
                        "classCode": "05",
                        "mathsMarks": "06",
                        "socialMarks": "05",
                        "englishMarks": "04",
                        "scienceMarks": "07"
                    },
                    {
                        "classCode": "11",
                        "mathsMarks": "90",
                        "socialMarks": "92",
                        "englishMarks": "95",
                        "scienceMarks": "91"
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Query",
    "graphQLAPIId": "4tbr6xolzjfctl5tdbiur7jqnu",
    "transformedTemplate": "{\"version\":\"2018-05-29\",\"operation\":\"Query
\",\"limit\":100,\"query\":{\"expression\":\"#gender = :gender AND #sortKey 
BETWEEN :sortKey0 AND :sortKey1\",\"expressionNames\":{\"#gender\":\"gender
\",\"#sortKey\":\"classCode#mathsMarks#socialMarks#englishMarks#scienceMarks
\"},\"expressionValues\":{\":gender\":{\"S\":\"m\"},\":sortKey0\":{\"S
\":\"05#06#05#04#07\"},\":sortKey1\":{\"S\":\"11#90#92#95#91\"}}},\"index
\":\"filterbyClassAndMarks\",\"scanIndexForward\":true}"

}
```

It is showing the scanned count as 0 in the result:

```
 "result": {
            "items": [],
            "scannedCount": 0
        },
```

And the final response is success with empty result as shown below:

```
Object { data: {…} }
​
data: Object { filterbyClassAndMarks: {…} }
​​
filterbyClassAndMarks: Object { items: [], nextToken: null }
​​​
items: Array []
​​​​
length: 0
​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​
nextToken: null

Array []
```

Key conditions on compound sort keys is possible [as per aws documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes-to-improve-query-performance-and-reduce-costs/)... I do not understand what I am missing exactly. Probably the GSI index is not properly configured/written.

Since most of the time the result is less than 1% of records in the table and is read intensive, scanning/reading all the records and filtering them is a very naive solution. Need better solution either with indices or otherwise.

SECOND EDIT:
[Example of expected behavior of applying hash key and compound sort key before filtering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg2r2.png). The example is given to highlight expected behavior only and does not indicate approximate percentage of records not read due to hash key or compound sort key.

Comment: I don't know if you can create a compound sort key that will satisfy an arbitrary query. How would you do this in an RDBMS without an equivalent scan/filter?

Comment: I do not know how it is done in RDBMS, However Key conditions on compound sort keys is possible as per [aws documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes-to-improve-query-performance-and-reduce-costs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB does not excel in supporting ad-hoc queries among an arbitrary list of attributes.  If you want to fetch the same item using an undefined (or large) number of attributes(e.g. fetch student by mathMarks, socialMarks, scienceMarks, name, gender, etc) you will be better off using something other than DynamoDB.

EDIT:

You've updated your question with information that fundamentally changes the access pattern.  You initially said

> I want to fetch records of all male or female students from dynamodb who have secured more than x1 marks in maths, more than x2 marks in science, less than y1 marks in social and less than y2 marks in English...

and later changed this access pattern to say (emphasis mine)

> I want to fetch records of all male or female students **from class 5 to class 11** who have secured between x1 and x2 marks in maths, between y1 and y2 marks in science, between z1 and z2 marks in english and between w1 and w2 marks in social

Partitioning your data on gender and class range *might* allow you to implement this access pattern.  You also removed `... other variables` from your example schema, suggesting you might have a fixed list of marks include math, science, social, and English.  This is less important than gender and class, but hear me out :)

You didn't mention it in your original question, but your data suggests you have a `fetch Student by ID` access pattern.  So I started by defining students by ID:

[image]

The partition key is STUDENT#student_id and the sort key is `A`.  I sometimes use "METADATA" or "META" as the sort key, but "A" is nice and short.

To support your primary access pattern, I created a global secondary index named `GSI1`, with PK and SK attributes of `GSI1PK` and `GSI1SK`.  I assigned GSI1PK `STUDENTS#gender` and GSISK is the `class` attribute.

[image]

This partitions your data by gender and class.  To narrow your results even further, you'd need to use filters on the various marks.  For example, if you wanted to fetch all make students between class 5 and 9 with specific marks, you could do the following (in DynamoDB pseudocode):

```
QUERY from GSI1 where PK=STUDENTS#M SK BETWEEN 05 and 09
      FILTER englishMark BETWEEN 009 and 050 AND
             mathsMark BETWEEN 050 and 075 AND
             scienceMark BETWEEN 045 and 065 AND
             socialMark BETWEEN 020 and 035 AND
```

Filtering in DynamoDB doesn't work like most people think.  When filtering, DynamoDB:

1. Read items from the table
2. Apply filter to remove items that don't match
3. Return items

This can lead to awful performance (and cost) if you have a large table and are filtering for a very small set of data.  For example, if you're executing a `scan` operation on terabytes of data and applying filters to identify a single item, you're going to have a bad time.

However, there are circumstances where filtering is a fine solution.  One example is when you can use the Partition Key and Sort Key to narrow the set of data you're working with *before* applying a filter.  In the above example, I'm dividing your data by gender (perhaps dividing your search space in half) before further narrowing the items by class.  The amount of data you're left with might be small enough to filter out the remaining items effectively.

However, I'll point out that gender has rather *low* cardinality.  Perhaps there are more specifics about your access pattern that could help with that.  For example, maybe you could group students by primary/secondary school and create a PK of STUDENTS#F#1-5.  Maybe you could group them by the school district, or zip code?  No detail about access patterns is too specific when working with NoSQL databases!

The point of this exercise is to illustrate two points:

1. Filtering in DynamoDB is best achieved by selecting a good primary key.
2. Using the DynamoDB filtering mechanism is best used on smaller subsets of your data.  Don't be afraid to use it in the right places!

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation of pk,sk and filtering concepts. Apologies if i am not putting question rightly. My focus is on constructing  a compound sort key with 2 or more variables and apply key conditions  so that resulting subset before filtering is minimized as far as possible as explained in my [SECOND EDIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg2r2.png).

Comment: Compound sort keys won't work for this access pattern.  You can't concatenate several numerical values together and perform rage queries across each of them selectively.

Comment: @Phoenix if this was useful to you, consider accepting it as the answer so others may benefit from the response.